# ioS Swift: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

While trying to read contents of a file into a var:

```
var mytext = ""
...
println(downloadFilePath)
mytext = String(contentsOfFile: downloadFilePath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)!
```

I get this error:
 *Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value*

The file itself is present, and it is generated earlier. The size and contents of the file may vary at each run. The same code works sometimes.

Could it be size of the file (21K) or contents - which cause this?

Comment: If you want to avoid the only crash you can use if let.

Comment: let me guess. `downloadFilePath` is `nil`. Put a breakpoint in the `myText = String...` line and check it.

Comment: mustafa> I am printing the downloadFilePath and it does not show nil. It prints a valid value, and i have checked presence of the file itself from command line too.

Comment: 1) Use optional binding instead of forced unwrapping. – 2) Use the `error:` parameter to get information about the problem. – *Possible* problem: The data does not represent valid UTF-8.

Comment: Martin R> Indeed the issue was with encoding. The error object says Cocoa Error 261, so i changed to using ASCII Encoding as follows: mytext = String(contentsOfFile: downloadFilePath, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding, error: &error)!   , and that works.

Answer (score 1):

> Trust me, compiler. I know what I'm doing. I'm taking off my seatbelt and helmet.

That's what you tell the compiler when you use the force-unwrap operator, `!`, or deal with an "implicitly unwrapped optional" type such as `String!`. This is something I avoid at all costs. Try restructuring your code like this:

```
assert(nil != (downloadFilePath as String?))
var error: NSError? = nil
if let mytext = String(contentsOfFile: downloadFilePath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error) {
    println("contentsOfFile was called successfully!")
    println("mytext: \(mytext)")
} else {
    println("I should implement error handling. What happened? \(error)")
    assertionFailure("Until I have a UI for telling the user about the fail, let's just visit the debugger.")
}
```

There are two techniques in here that I use to help keep my code happy:

- Use your [assertions](http://swiftdoc.org/func/assert/) and [preconditions](http://swiftdoc.org/func/precondition/). Crash at the earliest sign of unrecoverable failure. A dead program normally does a lot less damage than a crippled one, quoth the [PragProg Tips](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips). Assertions also serve as executable documentation: If you assert a certain state, the next programmer reading your code can reason about possible states in your method.
- Until your world is entirely safe from `nil` (which it isn't if you're using Foundation or introduce a `!` force-unwrap into your code), you may find `nil` in non-optional types as the error shows. If you suspect this, turn the non-optional into an optional and check it. I threw together a few [examples](https://gist.github.com/wjlafrance/8334888cd83c306fed8c) of how you can deal with these sneaky nils. Combine these with assertions around method calls that don't express their contracts in their signatures.